# Maven maven-enforcer-plugin POM configuration not honored

Tags: java, maven

I am having some issues with local non release builds. I am upgrading our Java repository from Java 8 to 11. Ever since I have been updating package dependencies to pass the build which all got resolved but for some reason for our dev package I am getting "No Snapshots allowed" I have been trying different POM configurations to bypass that error as it is a dev build and snapshots should be fine.

My latest configuration in the parent pom has the following

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>
```

Nevertheless I tried many variations by also trying out configurations from the maven site directly like https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html and have been trying to apply not just to the parent but the child folders as well.

The reason I am saying is it is not being honored is when I try a different message for this block: `<message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>` I still get the default message and not my custom message. But if I change the version it seems to be honored.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I mean, if you say `<skip>true</skip>`, it is just skipped...

Comment: But that is the thing it is not skipping the enforcer. I also have tried a different config directly from maven and also adjusted it to exclude some snapshots wild a wild card for example but that was not honored either it would still throw the snapshot error

`nuxeo-studio:xxx-xxx-dam:jar:lts2021-SNAPSHOT <--- is not a release dependency` I will get this even when having added this:

`<requireReleaseDeps>
  <message>No Snapshots Allowed!!!!</message>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>nuxeo-studio:*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</requireReleaseDeps>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the solution to this problem due to working with Nuxeo packages the below property is not working
`<properties> <enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip> </properties>`

But this property is
`<properties> <nuxeo.skip.enforcer>true</nuxeo.skip.enforcer> </properties>`